# RHEL: 10.6.5. Checking if chrony is synchronized - selected sources does not match chronyd selected sources

Tags: freeipa, chrony

I need clarification on these synchronizing results,

```
[root@rockyidm1a etc]# systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-04-05 15:18:23 MDT; 20min ago
       Docs: man:chronyd(8)
             man:chrony.conf(5)
    Process: 1116 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1150 (chronyd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 48624)
     Memory: 3.7M
        CPU: 61ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
             └─1150 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F 2

Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a systemd[1]: Starting NTP client/server...
Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: chronyd version 4.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: Frequency 8.230 +/- 0.248 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data
Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: Loaded seccomp filter (level 2)
Apr 05 15:18:23 rockyidm1a systemd[1]: Started NTP client/server.
Apr 05 15:18:32 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: Selected source 107.155.79.3 (2.rocky.pool.ntp.org)
Apr 05 15:18:32 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: System clock TAI offset set to 37 seconds
Apr 05 15:32:35 rockyidm1a chronyd[1150]: Selected source 165.140.142.118 (2.rocky.pool.ntp.org)
```

the selected sources are,

```
Selected source 107.155.79.3 (2.rocky.pool.ntp.org)
Selected source 165.140.142.118 (2.rocky.pool.ntp.org)
```

however,

```
[root@rockyidm1a etc]# chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : A58C8E76 (ns.august.tw)
Stratum         : 3
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Apr 05 21:40:08 2023
System time     : 0.000143721 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000076564 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000085321 seconds
Frequency       : 8.221 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.011 ppm
Skew            : 0.230 ppm
Root delay      : 0.057729453 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.017027335 seconds
Update interval : 259.2 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Reference ID is

```
Reference ID    : A58C8E76 (ns.august.tw)
```

> This is the reference ID and name (or IP address) if available, of the server to which the computer is
> currently synchronized.

and the selected sources of Rocky is not listed here,

```
[root@rockyidm1a etc]# chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^+ 108.61.23.93.vultruserco>     2   7   377    67   +521us[ +521us] +/-   67ms
^+ mail.trafficsystem.com.mx     2   6   377     5    +56us[  +56us] +/-   49ms
^* ns.august.tw                  2   7   265    73   -900us[-1046us] +/-   58ms
^+ 143-42-229-154.ip.linode>     2   8   377    11   +742us[ +742us] +/-   88ms
```

What is causing the different select source results and if not normal, how can this be corrected?  I need this to be correct before installing FreeIPA.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
After further research, configuring *chronyd* on the IDM Server and some clients to sync with pfSense NTP Server, it appears good, pfSense NTP UI is all I need to make any adjustments and I don't need any SRV record look-ups, because the IDM will default to using *chronyd* configuration.

I removed the pool setting, added the server directive in the chrony.conf to **server 10.30.70.1 iburst** which is the IP to pfSense LAN Gateway and add the pools there. This way I will just have a single configuration to deal with.

My NTP Network Topology:

[image]

```
[root@idmserver1c etc]# systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-04-03 12:39:42 MDT; 2 days ago
       Docs: man:chronyd(8)
             man:chrony.conf(5)
    Process: 7166 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 7168 (chronyd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 48621)
     Memory: 1.3M
        CPU: 569ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
             └─7168 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F 2

Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com systemd[1]: Starting NTP client/server...
Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: chronyd version 4.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: Frequency 7.995 +/- 0.113 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com systemd[1]: Started NTP client/server.
Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data
Apr 03 12:39:42 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: Loaded seccomp filter (level 2)
Apr 03 12:39:46 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: Selected source 10.30.70.1
Apr 03 12:39:46 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: System clock TAI offset set to 37 seconds
```

selected source

> Apr 03 12:39:46 idmserver1c.kbbn-7.com chronyd[7168]: Selected source 10.30.70.1

```
[root@idmserver1c etc]# chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 0A1E4601 (pfSense.kbbn-7.com)
Stratum         : 4
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Apr 06 02:32:55 2023
System time     : 0.000002979 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : -0.000001970 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000022135 seconds
Frequency       : 8.331 ppm fast
Residual freq   : -0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.027 ppm
Root delay      : 0.050869167 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.028909940 seconds
Update interval : 256.4 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Reference ID

> Reference ID    : 0A1E4601 (pfSense.kbbn-7.com)

and

```
[root@idmserver1c etc]#  chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^* pfSense.kbbn-7.com            3   9   377   265    -13us[  -15us] +/-   71ms
```

finally

```
[root@idmserver1c etc]# chronyc sourcestats
Name/IP Address            NP  NR  Span  Frequency  Freq Skew  Offset  Std Dev
==============================================================================
pfSense.kbbn-7.com         20  11   58m     -0.000      0.026    -28ns    30us
```

Comment: nice architecture. I'm curious, which program did you use to draw the diagram? @VcDeveloper